# Requirements.txt causes an error when I'm deploying my Django app to the Azure web app service

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, requirements.txt

I've got a Django app hosted on the Azure web app service. I recently removed the `skipPythonDeployment` file, so that I can add custom packages from my requirements.txt file. At first this worked fine when I added just the crispy forms package. But after that, I wanted to update my Django installation to 1.11 (the default version in the app service is 1.9.4).

So this is what my requirements.txt looks currently:

```
django<2
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
```

Now, when I try to push my commits to the server (`git push azure master`)
I get the following deployment log:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 308 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: .............................................
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '763167dc3c'.
remote: Generating deployment script.
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling python deployment.
remote: Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps 
with a .skipPythonDeployment file.
remote: Detecting Python runtime from site configuration
remote: Detected python-2.7
remote: Found compatible virtual environment.
remote: Pip install requirements.
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://username@project.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/b
```

I've tried to look at Azures commit logs but the error is pretty much the same:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling python deployment.
Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with a 
.skipPythonDeployment file.
Detecting Python runtime from site configuration
Detected python-2.7
Found compatible virtual environment.
Pip install requirements.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files 
(x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\65.60816.2969\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd 
"D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Or where I could see the actual error?

**EDIT**

This github thread (https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/DjangoAzure/issues/2) provided a workaround, by deleting env/azure.env.python-2.7.txt from the server, but it doesn't explain why the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is some pip error. In Azure, you can see the pip log output on the "Deployment options" blade. (You may need to configure the web app to track your git branch and automatically sync with it if you haven't already.) If your most recent deployment failed, you would see a red exclamation point; click on that deployment and then click "View log" next to your deployment command. This will let you see the pip output and what went wrong.

You can also access the pip logs on your app server if you access the FTP site.

[image: Azure deployment steps]